# Как должно выглядеть регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Только начал изучать регулярные выражения. Как получить значение между *filter* и *apply* (*result*)? При этом *dir* и *result* может быть любым словом (латиница) или цифрой.

```
/dir/filter/result/apply/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так. Внутри группа в скобках . любой символ * квантификатор 0 или больше, ? лечит * от жадности.

```
filter\/(.*?)\/apply
```